# How would I install CSFML 2.5 on Linux?

Tags: linux, software-installation, graphics

For the last couple of days, I have had a lot of trouble installing CSFML 2.5 on Linux.

First of all, I tried to install CSFML by calling:

`sudo apt-get install csfml-dev`

This only partially worked, for some reason it installed version **2.4 for graphics and 2.5 for system**, which made it impossible to run my project to due version conflicts.

I have tried to look everywhere online for help on installing CSFML 2.5 on Linux but I have been unable to find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't say what your Linux distro is, but that would be necessary for us to reproduce your two-version installation problem. But as a general suspicion: when apt installs something, the versions it installs do match. Chances are whatever you're building finds another set of development headers than those you installed via apt.